# Making a scope for Users with no role (rolify)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, rolify

Im having trouble to show the photos from a my `User`model.

I want to show the photos ONLY from the users that don't have role assigned with rolify.

So, I need to create a query for it:

```
@photos = Photo.where(User.find_by(Role == nil))
```

I can't get the scope to work...

Can someone give it a try?

Thanks!

Comment: `User.includes(:photos).where.not(role: null)` will work ?

Comment: Try this: `Photo.includes(user: :roles).where(roles: { id: nil })`

Comment: Great stuff MrYoshji, apparently it works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

To get all users with no role:

```
User.with_role(nil)
```

So, assuming that Photo belongs_to :user (photos table should have a user_id column):

```
@photos = Photo.where(user_id: User.with_role(nil))
```